# call 'go build' command from golang os.exec

Tags: go

in my project, i need to write some go code dynamically and need to test the code is valid. so need to call "go build" command  use 'os.exec' function.

when i write go code in a temp directory like '/data/test/mycode.go'. and i try to call 'go build', they return a error as 'no such file or directory'.
how i can do this correctly? thanks all:)

below is some code '

```
// is not work too
// goPath, err := exec.LookPath("go")

var out, stderr bytes.Buffer
cmd := exec.Command(fmt.Sprintf("%s/go build /data/test/mycode.go", goPath))
cmd.Stdout = &out
cmd.Stderr = &stderr
err = cmd.Run()
```

PS: but i call the command 'go build /data/test/mycode.go' directly in terminal. it can works.

Comment: You are executing a program named something like "/usr/local/bin/go build /data/test/mycode.go" with exactly zero arguments. You should provide each argument ("build" and "/data/test/mycode.go") individually, that's what exec.Command `arg ...string` is good for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fmt.Sprintf("%s/go build /data/test/mycode.go", goPath) string` returns a single string internally divided by a blank space, but as a single string.

`os/exec.Command(name string, arg ...string) *Cmd`
expects a few arguments. It won't divide one string itself.